# can I import JSON data into database with my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ajax, json

I have one rails application.
I have got JSON data via Ajax call, and now I want to import my JSON data into application database. How can I archive this? Can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

---Update---
My application has a Task model, and User model. User has many tasks, and Task belongs to a user. After user log in, I will make an Ajax call (jQuery getJSON) get JSON data from another service provider. I want to import JSON data into database as tasks.

----Add Sample Json Data----

```
  {
   "server_time":"2010-12-22 15:27:04 +0800",
     "entries":[
       {
         "all_day":true,
         "archived":null,
         "assignment":null,
         "attribute":"plan",
         "completed":null,
         "context":null,
         "created":"2010-12-14 14:50:24 +0800",
         "deleted":null,
         "end_at":null,
         "forwarded_by":null,
         "id":"jee+ypfERGSCqlXjuyUjYw==",
         "notes":"",
         "priority":0,
         "project":null,
         "reminders":[],
         "repeat_no":null,
         "repeater":null,
         "start_at":"2010-12-14 00:00:00 +0800",
         "tags":[],
         "title":"xcv",
         "trashed":null,
         "updated":"2010-12-14 14:50:24 +0800",
         "hidden":null
       }
       ...
       {
         "all_day":true,
         "archived":null,
         "assignment":null,
         "attribute":"inbox",
         "completed":null,
         "context":null,
         "created":"2010-12-15 16:12:24 +0800",
         "deleted":null,
         "end_at":null,
         "forwarded_by":null,
         "id":"MOAvW5IBTXScMVq2WdXFXQ==",
         "notes":"",
         "priority":0,
         "project":"z1",
         "reminders":[],
         "repeat_no":null,
         "repeater":null,
         "start_at":null,
         "tags":[],
         "title":"3",
         "trashed":null,
         "updated":"2010-12-15 16:12:24 +0800",
         "hidden":null
       },
       {
         "all_day":true ,
         "archived":null,
         "assignment":null,
         "attribute":"plan",
         "completed":null,
         "context":null,
         "created":"2010-12-15 18:29:27 +0800",
         "deleted":null,
         "end_at":null,
         "forwarded_by":null,
         "id":"dSOHwcYQRbmTCO+wjtUUaQ==",
         "notes":"",
         "priority":0,
         "project":null,
         "reminders":[],
         "repeat_no":null,
         "repeater":null,
         "start_at":"2010-12-17 00:00:00 +0800",
         "tags":[],
         "title":"after day",
         "trashed":null,
         "updated":"2010-12-15 18:29:27 +0800",
         "hidden":null
       }
     ],
   "addtional":"full"
 }
```

Comment: It might help if you add more detail around how you want the data to be persisted in the database. Does this data correspond to a model or do you just want the raw JSON data in a MySQL database?

Comment: Hello Pan, I've added update information.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the updated information. If you add a sample result from the getJSON call to your question then the answerer can write you a code sample to import that data. Are you using MySQL?

Comment: Hello Pan, thanks. I've already added the sample data of that JSON file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't already have the JSON gem, you can install it via command line:

```
gem install json
```

That will allow you to parse the JSON into its equivalent Ruby data structures.

If the JSON already matches your model, you just need to do something like:

```
new_record = Model.new(JSON.parse(json_string_from_external_service)) 
new_record.save
```

If it does not already match your model, you can do:

```
a_hash = JSON.parse(json_string_from_external_service)
```

Then you just copy over your attributes and save:

```
new_record = Model.new
new_record.attribute_1 = a_hash['key_for_attribute_1']
... etc ...
new_record.save
```